# How to find the winner of a modified othello/reversi game?

Tags: algorithm

I came across this interview question on another site.

In the game of Othello, red or black disks are placed on a 8x8 grid following certain rules. Players choose their color, and the player with the maximum number of disks on the grid win.

Given a two 2D arrays(one for red, the other for black) signifying the presence/absence of a disk, and the following rules:

- For a sequence of length n > 3, assign (n-2) as points for that player
- Sequences can be vertical, horizontal or diagonal
- A disk cannot belong to multiple sequences

e.g. For the following 2D array, the points would be the maximum of the diagonal elements (including [0,0]) and the elements in the first row (excluding [0,0]), or that of diagonal elements (excluding [0,0]) and horizontal elements (including [0,0]). i.e.max(4+0, 3+2) = 5

1 1 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1

Determine the winner by maximum points.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, even though you might find a simpler one.

To compute the score of a player, aloocate a 8X8 2D array of structs, which contains the following fields:
vertical, horizontal, diagonal1, diagonal2.

At the end of the algorithm's execution, this four fields will hold the sequence's size "so far" - As an example, the 'vertical' field of cell (x,y) holds 1 if there is a disc at this cell, and there is no disc at (x,y-1), 2 if there are discs at (x,y) and at (x,y-1) but no disc at (x, y-2) etc. The same about the 3 other fields.
You also need a score variable, to sum the achieved score.

Now you should go through this array row by row in ascending order, starting from the (0,0) cell [(0,0),(0,1)....(0,7),(1,0)...], and fill the structs. At each cell you first check if there is a disc at the equivalent cell at the original 2D array. If there is no disc, you should keep the score, and set all the fields of the current cell's struct to 0. If there is a disc (let's say the currnet cell is (x,y)), you should assign as follows:

```
(x,y)->vertical = (x,y-1)->vertical,
(x,y)->horizontal = (x-1,y)->horizontal,
(x,y)->diagonal1 = (x-1,y-1)->diagonal1,
(x,y)->diagonal2 = (x+1,y-1)->diagonal2.
```

Notice that at each point all the values that you need are already computed. In case of out of bounds (x-1 < 0 etc.), the value is 0.
You should also increase the score counter by 2 for every field you assigned 4 or by 1 for every field you assigned 5 or more (this will give n-2 points to each sequence of length n > 3).

That's all. After going through all the 2D array the score counter will hold the player's score.

The complexity is O(n^2), which is not bad at all (actually you can't find a better solution in terms of complexity).

Comment: After creating the 2D Array of structs, how do we select the components to be added (diag,vert,hor) to the score ? [In this example,](http://pastebin.com/QNrDG4tp) 
How will we handle the element at [0,0], the correct score would choose the score of the diagonal, while your algorithm would select both the first horizontal row and the diagonal.

Comment: I suppose i didn't understand the rules. I thought that you should give point to each sequence, independently. So what the rules are?

Comment: I have edited the question. It's the same, but each sequence has to be counted only once.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding the rules try this link [www.springfrog.com/games/othello/othello.htm](http://www.springfrog.com/games/othello/othello.htm)

data structure used:

board: int[8][8];

uncounted_red: 2, uncounted_black: -2, empty: 0;

counted_red: 1, counted_black: -1

score_red: int, score_black: int;

---

Algorithm:

1. Find sequences with consecutive red with length > 3
2. For each sequence found add score length - 2
3. Further reduce the score by already counted pegs encountered in the sequence.
4. After calculating the score mark all uncounted pegs as counted.
5. Repeat the process for black.
6. winner = score_red > score_black ? red : black.

---

The problem reduces now to how do you perform step 1.